# Do Action After audio.ended

Tags: javascript, audio, timer

Trying to learn some simple JS stuff with audio since I do a lot of audio work I figured I would learn how to embed some into a site of mine, not to mention just brush up on some simple web programming.

I wanted to have an action after the audio file finished playing however a while(1) loop checking audio.ended immediately crashes.

I decided to use setInterval to check every second however this does not seem to work either. No crash but nothing happens. I've checked through the Mozilla documentation and as far as I can see with my limited experience there is no obvious solution.

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.id = 'audio';
audio.src = 'track01.mp3';  
audio.play();
setInterval(checkFinished(), 1000);

function checkFinished()
{
    if(audio.ended == false)
    {
        document.write(audio.ended.toString());
    }
    else
    {
        document.write(audio.ended.toString());
        foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an Event, instead.

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio'); audio.id = 'audio';
audio.src = 'track01.mp3'; 
document.body.appendChild(audio); // append somewhere else if wanted 
audio.play();
audio.onended = function(){
  console.log('You do say.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by PHPglue, you can use .onended.

here's an example:

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="track01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.onended = function() {
    alert("The audio has ceased");
};
</script>
```

(I don't like needless js, but the script part is still applicable of you just use js for the audio)

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp for some info

Comment: No. I didn't see it was accepted. Some one can At least use the link for reference.

Comment: I thought the point was to try give as much info on a question as possible? I showed a way to use audio tags to play audio rather than relying on javascript and gave a link to a website to further explain it.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I was previously not familiar with the js event system.